# mysql query returns two results instead of one

Tags: mysql, sql

I noticed this because for some words it returned the wrong etymology. So I noticed that the query returns many results instead of one. the table has about 60000 entries.

so here is my mysql query:

```
conMySQL.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL; DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=" & MYSQLserverIP & ";Port=" & MYSQLserverPort & ";DATABASE=" & MYSQLserverDB & ";UID=" & MYSQLserverUser & ";PASSWORD=" & MYSQLserverPass & ";OPTION=3;Connect Timeout=1;"
conMySQL.Open
If conMySQL.State = 1 Then
    recMySQL.Open "SELECT * FROM tEtymology WHERE sLemma='" & sLemma & "'", conMySQL, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    If Not (recMySQL.EOF And recMySQL.BOF) Then
        recMySQL.MoveFirst
        strReturn = sLemma & "<br>" & recMySQL.Fields("id").Value & "#" & recMySQL.Fields("sLemma").Value & "#" & recMySQL.Fields("sEtymology").Value
        recMySQL.MoveNext
        strReturn = strReturn & "<br>" & recMySQL.Fields("id").Value & "#" & recMySQL.Fields("sLemma").Value & "#" & recMySQL.Fields("sEtymology").Value
    End If
End If
```

for example, for the Lemma "μπότα" the result is:

```
μπότα
34288#μπότα#[<μσν. μπότα < γαλλ. botte]
38505#οπότε#[<αρχ. ὁπόταν, με επίδραση του ὅτε]
```

this happens for many words, not only for the one you see here. I tried removing the index in the sLemma field ( thought that the indexed entry is a hashed value and due to collision it becomes the same ), but no change. I also tried changing the collation of the sLemma column but nothing changed.

so what i understand from this is that for mysql μπότα=μπότα and μπότα=οπότε which doesn't make any sense. There is only one entry "μπότα" in the sLemma column.

Any ideas ?

**edit**: here is how the entries look in phpmyadmin

[image]

you may think it's the same entry ( the red ones with the IDs mentioned here ) but if you zoom the image you will see they are different letters ( first and last letter ).

Comment: Does the column `sLemma` have a unique constraint on it?

Comment: try to select **distinct**  FROM tEtymology WHERE sLemma='"......

Comment: sLemma doesn't have a unique constraint. using DISTINCT doesn't change anything, still returns two results.

Comment: Try doing just 'select distinct sLemma FROM ...' rather than 'distinct *' - I am wondering whether this is a character encoding issue. Presumably you are using a database installation that supports these characters? Try creating a new table with just a single column and a unique constraint and inserting those two values?

Comment: @Matt when i do "select distinct sLemma From" it only returns one value, "μπότα". Please check my screenshot attached above about how the words look through phpmyadmin.

Comment: indeed, if i make it unique, i get an error for duplicate entry on insert. it must be a character encoding issue.

Comment: Please note that you appear to be wide-open to SQL Injection - please use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments and testing, almost certainly a character encoding issue. Not sure which character set you are currently using but you could try something like 'greek' (ISO 8859-7 Greek) - other possibilities here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-charsets.html

Some character charts for each character set here: http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/

There is also some stuff to note about setting the character set being used by your connection (not just the actual server) if changing the character set on the db doesn't solve it. Hope that helps!

EDIT

Apparently you can use the command

```
show variables like 'char%';
```

to see all your current character set encodings. I came across this blog on the topic which is not exactly the same, but quite interesting: https://www.bluebox.net/insight/blog-article/getting-out-of-mysql-character-set-hell